# compiling cryptdb.dll example from firebird 3.0.3 is not working

Tags: delphi, encryption, firebird

I'm trying to build it with Delphi Tokyo, and when I try to encrypt the database I'm getting the message:

- Error loading plugin cryptdb.dll

- Module {FIREBIRDDIR}\plugins\cryptdb.dll does not contain plugin cryptdb.dll type 9

My steps:

1. Installed Firebird 3.0.3 (NNF)
2. Rename {FIREBIRDDIR}\examples\dbcrypt\crypdb.pas to cryptdb.dpr, and build
3. Copied cryptdb.dll to {FIREBIRDDIR}\plugins
4. isql employee2.fdb -user sysdba -pass masterkey
5. alter database encrypt with "cryptdb.dll";
6. no joy, the obnoxious error message appears.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming you have setup both plugins.conf and firebird.conf and matched capitalization between registerPluginFactory and firebird.conf entry (required in July 2017) then this worked for me: SQL> alter database encrypt with cryptDb key nada;

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit or 32 bit Firebird, did you compile the DLL as 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: I also hope you are aware the the crypt-plugin example is a toy example: it applies an extremely easy to crack XOR algorithm, so you should not use the example in production and expect it to offer any protection whatsoever.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: 32bits, and yes i just want the "hello world"

Comment: @FredS: i just do a ctrl-c/ctrl-v in plugins.conf changing UDR to CRYPTDB. Nothing on firebird.conf. Could you post your confs?

Comment: I suggest you post this question to the firebird-devel mailing list; I'm not sure you'll be able to get an answer here.

Comment: I believe the correct thing to do is for you to post your settings with your question. I am reluctant to add what I have as an answer since I am going from notes from July against a snapshot. That said, if you didn't get your Firebird.pas by compiling the correct Firebird Master then it may be what's causing the "type 9" error. The IMaster const in that generated file is Version=12.

Comment: @FredS:Sorry, but i´dont understant what are you asking. Everything are in default state (right after installation, nothing was done). Firebird.pas comes from {FIREBIRD}\include\firebird\firebird.pas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Dimitry on the firebird-support mailing list, the name of the plugin is `cryptdb`, not `cryptdb.dll`.

Instead you need to use

```
alter database encrypt with cryptdb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've verified what's in my Notes still works.
*Change names as needed*

Add to plugins.conf:

```
Plugin = CRYPTDB {
Module = $(dir_plugins)/cryptDbPlugIn
}
```

To encrypt the initial db:

```
firebird>isql localhost:"..\db\UDFEncr.FDB" -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey
SQL> alter database encrypt with cryptDb key nada;
```

The Firebird.pas file that came with the snapshot back in July did not match the snapshot. I had to compiler generate it from Master.

[URL to GitHub for generated Firebird.pas](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B3_0_Release/src/include/gen/Firebird.pas)

Comment: The `WireCryptPlugin` setting is for the wire protocol encryption, not for the database encryption. Changing the `WireCrypt` and `WireCryptPlugin` setting are not relevant for database encryption at best, at worst it degrades security as Firebird will no longer encrypt the connection as the plugin is not a wire protocol encryption plugin. Are you confusing it with the `KeyHolderPlugin` setting?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: Looks that way, the solution that made it work was to generate Firebird.pas.

Answer (score 0):

You must change this line do match you dll file. In your case:

pluginManager.registerPluginFactory(IPluginManager.TYPE_DB_CRYPT, 'cryptdb', factory);